# How to fix spacing in display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have a list with this styling:

```
.og-details li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #999;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
```

The result is:

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix this? I have tried `vertical-align:top;` but it has not fixed the issue.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qb8mcq29/)**

Comment: pl provide jsfiddle link

Comment: I guess you are maintaining list row wise, instead create 3 different column and maintain your list separately

Comment: You should use CSS3 column layouts instead.

Comment: @Etash its in wordpress and this is dynamic content.

Comment: @muhammadumarfarooqfrank That doesn't mean you don't have control over the HTML WordPress generates. I'd also go with three separate lists. CSS columns are fine, but no support in IE9. Also, try floating these things instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qb8mcq29/3/)**

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #999;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: If you can go for JS fix for IE, refer  (http://www.cvwdesign.com/txp/article/360/multi-column-layout-with-css3-and-some-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
 <ul>
        <li>Pre-shipment Inspection</li>
        <li>Lift Examination</li>
        <li>Pressure Equipment Inspection Services</li>
        <li>Process and Plant Safety Audits</li>
        <li>Supplier Expediting Services</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Managed Services Solutions</li>
        <li>Industrial Inspection</li>
        <li>3<sup>rd</sup> party Inspection Services</li>
        <li>Supplier Evaluation Audit</li>
        <li>Lifting / Construction Equipments Inspection Services</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Equipment Integrity Services</li>
        <li>Risk Based Inspection</li>
        <li>worldwide inspection services at vendor premises / Final Inspection of Equipments</li>
        <li>Technical Inspection Services / Source Inspection including Steel Pipes, Vessels, Tanks, Exchangers, Valves, etc</li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #999;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
```

Check the following jsfiddle link.

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qb8mcq29/1/)

Comment: this is dynamic content . not static i need to fix this in one `UL`